# find values from a sorted vector which are also present in another sorted vector

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Suppose I have two sorted vectors (1D numpy ndarrays) A and B. I would like to find which values from vector A are also present in vector B. This is going to be the bottleneck of a certain function so I would like to make is as quick as possible. There is a function numpy.in1d which does exactly what I need. It can be boosted by telling the function the fact that values in the vectors are unique. OK, nice. But how about sorted values? I believe that knowing the values are sorted could boost the performance even more because it would be complexity O(1). But there is no argument to tell numpy.in1d that the vectors are sorted... Or is there any alternative or trick which can help me?

Comment: All the set operations in numpy use sorting. `np.in1d` and `np.intersect1d` will both sort the concatenation of the unique values in your two arrays. So you cannot escape a degradation to linearithmic performance even with your pre-sorted arrays. You could avoid `np.unique` resorting your already sorted arrays by replicating its source code (there is a link in the docs, and all the set operations in numpy are fully implemented in Python).

Answer (score 2):

`np.searchsorted` returns locations where corresponding values should be put without breaking sortedness.  In case your "haystack" array contains that value, it will be there.  You just need to compare values at those locations with needles. But be careful with out-of-bounds accesses: needle that is greater than maximum in haystack will produce `index == len(haystack)` and will generate `IndexError`.  You can use `np.take(..., mode='clip')` to return maximum for such values (and it will fail the equality test).

```
In [14]: haystack = np.array([1,2,4,5,8])

In [15]: needles = np.array([0,1,3,4,7,8,9])

In [16]: haystack.take(np.searchsorted(haystack, needles), mode='clip')
Out[16]: array([1, 1, 4, 4, 8, 8, 8])

In [17]: haystack.take(np.searchsorted(haystack, needles), mode='clip') == needles
Out[17]: array([False,  True, False,  True, False,  True, False], dtype=bool)

In [18]: needles[haystack.take(np.searchsorted(haystack, needles), mode='clip') == needles]
Out[18]: array([1, 4, 8])
```

If you expect a lot of elements in `needles` greater than `haystack.max()`, you may want to trim `needles` before the search to avoid wasting space on extraneous elements

```
needles = needles[needles <= haystack.max()]
```

or even faster variant

```
needles = needles[:np.searchsorted(needles, haystack.max(), side='right')]
```

EDIT: This solution is `O(N*logM)`, `N = len(needles), M = len(haystack)`, although it doesn't employ the fact that needles are themselves sorted.  You can do this in Cython/C in `O(N + M)` which will be faster for large(r) `N`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could create set out of each vector and then use intersect on that sets.

I think vectors should allow building set out of them, something like:

```
a = set(vectorA)
b = set(vectorB)
commons = a.intersection(b)
```

Comment: A `set` intersection is quite fast, but converting a numpy array to a `set` is quite slow.  (Thus things like `numpy.in1d`.)  The conversion back and forth is going to be much slower than the actual operation.

Comment: I am pretty sure, the performance of this would be terribly bad. 1) I am not taking benefit from the fact I have already sorted values 2) I am moving from static type numpy array to dynamic type domain of plain Python. And then back again. So, well... no.

Comment: Actually there is similar function in numpy.intersect1d without the need to convert Python to/from numpy. But it does not benefit from sorted values.